# Print a link in php email body

Tags: php

I want to print 'click here' as a link in the php email body. Following the code that I have used.

```
$mail->Subject = "New leave request";
$mail->Body = "You have a leave request from $emp_name on $today. To conform this leave"?><?php echo'<a href="http://localhost:127/lms/index.php">Click Here</a>';
$mail_to = $email;
```

Even I checked it from all possible ways, still I could not able to do that. Please help !

Comment: Did you add headers before sending mails. What is your content type?

Comment: try something this: `$mail->Body = "You have a leave request from $emp_name on $today. To conform this leave <a href='http://localhost:127/lms/index.php'>Click Here</a>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set email format to HTML

```
$message = "<a href="http://localhost:127/lms/index.php">Click Here</a>";
$mail->IsHTML(true);// Set HTML TRUE
$mail->Body = $message;
```

Comment: Nice, Thank u in advance. Now it works from this way.

Comment: Bad answer as accepted... How this is possible?? But clue is good.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this:

```
$mail->MsgHTML("<b>Hi, your first SMTP mail has been received.<a href='http://localhost:127/lms/index.php'>Click Here</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

// with  html body

```
 $mail->Body = "<p>This is the HTML message body <b><a href='{$link_address}'> Link </a></b></p>";
```

// without html body

```
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";
```

```
$mail->Subject = "New leave request";
$mail->Body = "You have a leave request from {$emp_name} on {$today}. To conform this leave Click Here";
$mail_to = $email;
```

i hope it will be helpful